# Problems with tor ppa

Tags: 14.04, dpkg, ppa

I'm tried to fix a problem with tor ppa in my Ubuntu 14.04, but I can't.

I tried to use

```
root@vitor-HP:~# LANG=C dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of torchat:
torchat depends on tor; however:
Package tor is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package torchat (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tor-geoipdb:
tor-geoipdb depends on tor (>= 0.2.4.20-1); however:
Package tor is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package tor-geoipdb (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
torchat
tor-geoipdb
```

After I use

```
root@vitor-HP:~# LANG=C apt-get install -f -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
python-socksipy
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following extra packages will be installed:
tor
Suggested packages:
mixmaster xul-ext-torbutton socat tor-arm polipo privoxy apparmor-utils
The following NEW packages will be installed:
tor
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/789 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2673 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 259372 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../tor_0.2.4.20-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking tor (0.2.4.20-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/tor_0.2.4.20-1_amd64.deb     (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/tor', which is also in package tor-browser 3.5.4
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/tor_0.2.4.20-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@vitor-HP:~#
```

I already use

```
root@vitor-HP:~# LANG=C sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
 You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.   
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
tor-geoipdb : Depends: tor (>= 0.2.4.20-1) but it is not installed
torchat : Depends: tor but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
root@vitor-HP:~#
```

I use clean too

```
root@vitor-HP:~# LANG=C apt-get autoclean
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
root@vitor-HP:~#
```

And I did this

```
root@vitor-HP:~# LANG=C apt-cache policy
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-libreoffice,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=LibreOffice PPA,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-libreoffice,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=LibreOffice PPA,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/irie/blender/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-irie-blender,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=PPA for Blender 2.4 and 2.7,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/irie/blender/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-irie-blender,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=PPA for Blender 2.4 and 2.7,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/inkscape.dev/stable/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-inkscape.dev-stable,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Inkscape Stable,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/inkscape.dev/stable/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-inkscape.dev-stable,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Inkscape Stable,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-app-review-board,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Application Review Board PPA,c=main
     origin extras.ubuntu.com
 500 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-app-review-board,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Application Review Board PPA,c=main
     origin extras.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty/partner i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Canonical,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Partner archive,c=partner
     origin archive.canonical.com
 500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty/partner amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Canonical,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Partner archive,c=partner
     origin archive.canonical.com
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe Translation-en
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main Translation-en
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/universe Translation-en
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/main Translation-en
 100 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe Translation-pt_BR
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe Translation-pt
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe Translation-en
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted Translation-pt_BR
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted Translation-pt
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse Translation-pt_BR
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse Translation-pt
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse Translation-en
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-pt_BR
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-pt
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-en
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin br.archive.ubuntu.com
  Pinned packages:
  root@vitor-HP:~#
```

And I can't remove the tor .deb in `/var/cache/apt/archives/`

When I remove it

```
root@vitor-HP:/var/cache/apt/archives# ls
lock  partial  tor_0.2.4.20-1_amd64.deb
root@vitor-HP:/var/cache/apt/archives# rm tor_0.2.4.20-1_amd64.deb 
root@vitor-HP:/var/cache/apt/archives# ls
lock  partial
root@vitor-HP:/var/cache/apt/archives#
```

and...

```
root@vitor-HP:~# LANG=C apt-get remove tor-browser
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
tor-geoipdb : Depends: tor (>= 0.2.4.20-1) but it is not going to be installed
torchat : Depends: tor but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@vitor-HP:~#
```

It appear again when I boot my Ubuntu after.

Can somebody help me to fix this?

Comment: `trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/tor', which is also in package tor-browser 3.5.4` tells all you need to know. To fix this, you could uninstall `tor-browser`.

Comment: @saiarcot895 How can I overwrite '/usr/bin/tor'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to run the command:

```
 sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends application
```

This fixes the problem.

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue as it will still cause a package conflict that will not be recoverable ever.

Comment: No, @ThomasW for me fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the `tor-browser` package (version 3.5.4) installed, and `apt` and `dpkg` don't like it when you are overwriting an already-installed executable managed by the packaging system, with a new version provided by a different package.

You should maybe start by removing `tor-browser`, then try again.  (`sudo apt-get remove tor-browser`)

Comment: When I use sudo apt-get remove tor-browser appear this massege root@vitor-HP:~# LANG=C apt-get remove tor-browser
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree Reading state information... DoneYou might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:The following packages have unmet dependencies:tor-geoipdb : Depends: tor (>= 0.2.4.20-1) but it is not going to be installed torchat : Depends: tor but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or a new file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`:

```
deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org trusty main
deb-src http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org trusty main
```

Then add the gpg key used to sign the packages by running the following commands at your command prompt:

```
gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv 886DDD89
gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | sudo apt-key add -
```

You can install it with the following commands:

```
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install tor deb.torproject.org-keyring
```

Answer (score -2):

```
sudo apt-get remove tor-browser
```

do this, and the browser will be permanently removed.